# React Error Boundary never working at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I have a component which, within its render method, generates an error.

Higher up in the tree, the component is `connect()`ed to a resource using `react-redux` to fetch data, and I have other HOCS and so forth (injecting classes etc).

The component uses an error boundary in case (say) a property is missing from the resource supplied to it (common issue).

I've distilled minimal example, accessing a property of undefined to reproduce the same error:

```
import React from 'react'

// An Error Boundary which returns either a fallback component (if supplied to props) or (default) an empty div, instead of screwing up the whole tree
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      hasError: false,
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { hasError: true }
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true })
    console.log('do stuff with', error, info)
  }

  render() {
    console.log('RENDERING ERROR BOUNDARY WITH STATE:', this.state)
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      if (this.props.fallback) {
        return (this.props.fallback)
      }
      return (<div />)
    }
    return this.props.children
  }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const resource = undefined
    return (
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <p>{resource.missingProperty}</p>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent
```

Of course, attempting to render the component generates the following stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'missingProperty' of undefined
    at MyComponent.render (index.jsx:58)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15141)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15096)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15980)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19102)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19143)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:18350)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:19261)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20165)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:20075)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:20049)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:19904)
    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:19711)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:12936)
    at Connect.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:356)
    at Connect.onStateChange (connectAdvanced.js:205)
    at Object.notify (Subscription.js:23)
    at Subscription.notifyNestedSubs (Subscription.js:62)
    at Connect.onStateChange (connectAdvanced.js:202)
    at Object.notify (Subscription.js:23)
    at Subscription.notifyNestedSubs (Subscription.js:62)
    at Connect.onStateChange (connectAdvanced.js:202)
    at Object.dispatch (createStore.js:175)
    at e (<anonymous>:1:40553)
    at asyncDispatchMiddleware.js:33
    at middleware.js:13
    at middlewareCamel.js:13
    at middlewareDate.js:34
    at _callee$ (middleware.js:285)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:290)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:116)
    at step (asyncToGenerator.js:21)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32

The above error occurred in the <MyComponent> component:
    in MyComponent (created by Connect(MyComponent))
    in Connect(MyComponent) (at withCachedResource.js:43)
    in _class (created by StreamField)
    in div (at streamfield.js:17)
    in StreamField (at StoryDrawer.js:34)
    in div (created by Grid)
    in Grid (created by WithStyles(Grid))
    in WithStyles(Grid) (at GridItem.jsx:20)
    in GridItem (created by WithStyles(GridItem))
    in WithStyles(GridItem) (at StoryDrawer.js:33)
    in div (created by Grid)
    in Grid (created by WithStyles(Grid))
    in WithStyles(Grid) (at GridContainer.jsx:20)
    in GridContainer (created by WithStyles(GridContainer))
    in WithStyles(GridContainer) (at StoryDrawer.js:26)
    in StoryDrawer (created by WithStyles(StoryDrawer))
    in WithStyles(StoryDrawer) (created by Connect(WithStyles(StoryDrawer)))
    in Connect(WithStyles(StoryDrawer)) (at Map.js:264)
    in div (created by Paper)
    in Paper (created by WithStyles(Paper))
    in WithStyles(Paper) (created by Drawer)
    in Transition (created by Slide)
    in EventListener (created by Slide)
    in Slide (created by WithTheme(Slide))
    in WithTheme(Slide) (created by Drawer)
    in RootRef (created by Modal)
    in div (created by Modal)
    in Portal (created by Modal)
    in Modal (created by WithStyles(Modal))
    in WithStyles(Modal) (created by Drawer)
    in Drawer (created by WithStyles(Drawer))
    in WithStyles(Drawer) (at Map.js:252)
    in div (at Map.js:153)
    in Map (created by WithStyles(Map))
    in WithStyles(Map) (created by Connect(WithStyles(Map)))
    in Connect(WithStyles(Map)) (created by AddUrlProps(Connect(WithStyles(Map))))
    in AddUrlProps(Connect(WithStyles(Map))) (at MapPage.jsx:24)
    in div (at FullArea/index.js:43)
    in FullArea (at MapPage.jsx:22)
    in div (at MapPage.jsx:21)
    in MapPage (created by WithStyles(MapPage))
    in WithStyles(MapPage) (created by Connect(WithStyles(MapPage)))
    in Connect(WithStyles(MapPage)) (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:33)
    in Switch (at App.js:25)
    in div (at App.js:23)
    in App (at src/index.js:32)
    in RouterToUrlQuery (at src/index.js:31)
    in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
    in ConnectedRouter (at src/index.js:30)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:29)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit ... to learn more about error boundaries.
```

What's SUPER weird is that the ErrorBoundary `render()` method never prints to the console. It's as if that wrapper just doesn't exist, and react completely ignores it, rendering only the children directly. I've no idea how that's even possible.

I've pushed this onto a production server, and the same appears there, so I don't think it's to do with development vs production configuration.

#### Questions

1. Am I going crazy? Have I totally misunderstood what React Error Boundaries are for?
2. Could something higher up the call stack be interfering with the error handler somehow?

#### Solution from @thedude

Show the accepted answer some love with your votes, folks. The corrected solution (clear now I see it) is that the component producing the error has to be wrapped, not simply the elements that the component defines. Corrected code:

```
import React from 'react'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const resource = undefined
    return (
      <p>{resource.missingProperty}</p>
    )
  }
}

class MyBoundedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <MyComponent />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )
  }
}

export default MyBoundedComponent
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ErrorBoundry` is never rendered because the render method of `MyComponent` never returns.

The error occurs on every render.

`render` in react produces an representation of the element tree to be used by react, the error you caused short-circuits this process.

You can make your example work by wrapping the error boundary over `MyComponent` not inside it (in the component that renders `MyComponent`

Comment: Uh... ok. Thanks @thedude, I feel like this is step 1 in my learning curve here. Strictly though, the error (in real life) actually occurs on *first* render rather than every render. Doesn't this mean that error boundaries are only useful if the error occurs on subsequent renders?

Comment: It's more of a distinction between `createElement` which is what the your code in the render function does and when react is calling `render`

Comment: So how could I protect against an error that occurs in the first execution of the render() method?

Comment: Ah! Now I get it! Thanks @thedude - you are, in fact, the dude of the day today. Modified code and sent to staging server; it now works as expected in both dev and production environments.

Dan Abramov recommends not putting error boundaries in HOCs, but I'm inclined to disagree at this point, since I want to keep my component and its wrapped error handler encapsulated, as opposed to handling error a level up in the code. Still, that's a debate for another day, and this problem now solved. Thanks!